# Добавить <DIV> к картинке

Tags: html, css, html5

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную задачу:

1) Есть изображение.jpg с нарисованными кнопками

2) Нужно сделать это изображение фоном HTML документа, а на месте каждой нарисованной кнопки повесить DIV с особым позиционирование, которое не будет сбиваться при изменении размера изображения.

Т.е. как сделать так, чтобы изображение стало резиновым (адаптивным) и добавленные DIV элементы не разъезжались при изменении размера картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю изначально вычислить все пропорции картинки, т.е вычисляем сколько в процентах отдалена кнопка снизу, справа/слева и её ширину/высоту. Теперь при изменении ширины картинка будет уменьшаться, а вместе с ней и кнопки

```css
.background {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.background .image {display:inline-block;position:relative;width:100%;}
.background .image img {display:inline-block;width:100%;pointer-events: none;}
.background .image .button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 12%;
    width: 37.8%;
    height: 13.8%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.background .image .button.b0 {left: 6.9%;}
.background .image .button.b1 {right: 7.9%;}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z24fy.jpg">
    <div class="button b0"></div>
    <div class="button b1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за ответ. А как сделать так, чтобы этот фон был адаптивным, т.е. менялся при сужении браузера и при этом DIV элементы не съезжали? Есть возможность это сделать?

Comment: @caboke, то есть он полностью изменялся или просто сужался, растягивался и т. д.?

Comment: Да, чтобы при заходе с телефона, например, эта картинка подстраивалась под разрешения мобильного устройства и DIV элементы не разъезжались. Это возможно?

Comment: @caboke, а соотношение в картинки должно сохраняться? Или можно, что бы картинка растягивалась?

Comment: Соотношение сторон должно сохраняться. Например, если width становится 200px, то и height должен стать 200px.

Comment: @caboke, тогда нужно написать чуть-чуть сложноватый код.Если вы подождёте, то я его напишу сейчас

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50145/discussion-between-yuri-and-caboke).